# When do I need to invoke \phantomsection?

Tags: hyperref, links

Inspired by question [When do I need invoke \clearpage manually?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9191/when-do-i-need-invoke-clearpage-manually):

When do I need to invoke `\phantomsection`?

In what condition is invoking `\phantomsection` necessary?

Comment: Are there any other than `hyperref` applications?

Comment: See question in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7627/how-to-reference-paragraph and my answer there for an example why you want to use `\phantomsection{}`.

Comment: Have you found any answer which you can accept? I think there are quite many good ones.

Answer (score 132):

The `\phantomsection` command is nessesary for `hyperref` to jump to the correct page, in other words it puts a hyper marker on the page. For example a starred section or chapter added to the TOC would normally refer to the wrong place without `\phantomsection`

```
\chapter*{Extended Summary}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Extended Summary}%
\markboth{Extended Summary}{Extended Summary}%
```

I normaly put in the preamble the command

```
\providecommand\phantomsection{}
```

Your document can then be compiled with or without `hyperref` without an error

Comment: Especially elegant, your `\providecommand`

Comment: Is `hyperref` only application ?

Comment: @Grzegorz Wierzowiecki: Yes it is only nessesary for `hyperref` (`hyperref` defines it internaly)

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki: If you're content with this information, don't forget to accept the answer. If there's something else you want to know, let us know.

Comment: Since `hyperref` 2009/11/25 v6.79h `\phantomsection` is no longer necessary in this situation. With this usage, the anchor is put _after_  the chapter title.

Comment: @Heiko Oberdiek: Thank you, I did not know about the update (neither has the maintainer of memoir ;-) ).

Comment: Can you please explain why you use `\providecommand\phantomsection{}`?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 When hyperref is not loaded, it is not defined.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Is it just not need, or should it not be used?

Comment: @lcnittl It should not be used unless you want to have a wrong anchor position.

Comment: In my case I need it for ToC, LoF, LoT, and it needs a \cleardoublepage before to correctly place the mark on new page. I don't need it for `chapter*`, they work correctly already.

Comment: `\providecommand\phantomsection{}` command is brillant!

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 111):

I am providing a different answer to this question because the original answer is out of date.

The `\phantomsection` command is needed to create a link to a place in the document that is not a figure, equation, table, section, subsection, chapter, etc.

This is mostly used in conjunction with `\addcontentsline` or with `\label` and `\hyperref`. For example, the following code will create a contents line and a link to somewhere in the document.

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Some place in the document}
\label{some}
This is just \hyperref[some]{some place} in the document.
```

Without the `\phantomsection` line, both the contents line and the link would point to the beginning of the current section (or subsection, etc.)

In previous versions of `hyperref` (before 2009-11-25), you also had to use `\phantomsection` with unnumbered sections (e.g. `\section*`) to prevent links from pointing to the previous section. This is not necessary in up-to-date distributions.

Comment: Thank you for this informative answer.  Too bad I can't upvote it again.

Answer (score 11):

I've found none of the previous answers to work, but the below snippet works well:

```latex
\newpage
\phantomsection \label{listoffig}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures
```

Originally found on: http://sumanta679.wordpress.com/2009/05/15/latex-list-of-table-list-of-figures-and-bibliography-in-toc/

Comment: This looks very similar to the code Nathan Grigg posted: could you elaborate on the difference?

Comment: I didn't get Nathans code to work. Why? I couldn't tell you. But here's a solution that worked for me.

Comment: Adding `\newpage` before `\phantomsection` is what made it work for me.