# Is reStructuredText compatible with the memoir class?

Tags: memoir, pandoc, restructured-text

While I'm fine with writing "real" documents in full-blown LaTeX, I often switch to [reStructuredText](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReStructuredText) as a lightweight markup language for simplish documents (like  meeting notes and stuff). I was quite happy with my workflow (`file.txt -> rst2latex-2.6.py -> pdflatex -> file.pdf`) until I recently decided that I wanted to use the `memoir` class, just as I do for my real documents.

The [documentation for reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/latex.html#document-class) states that this class is supported via the `--documentclass=memoir` option. However, my document now fails to compile because of some command fragility issue I don't really understand :

Titles and section titles are converted to something in the lines of :

```
\title{\phantomsection%
  This it the title%
  \label{this-it-the-title}}
```

which `article` seems fine with, but which `memoir` chokes on (about 15 errors in the log file).

**Is this an obvious but undocumented bug, or did I do something obviously wrong in the first place ?**

Minimal (not)working example :

```
#!/bin/sh

rm -f test.*

cat >> test.txt <<EOF
This it the title
=================

this is dummy text
EOF

rst2latex-2.6.py -V
rst2latex-2.6.py --verbose --documentclass=memoir test.txt test.tex
pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
```

As for the output, I get out of it :

```
rst2latex-2.6.py (Docutils 0.9 [release], Python 2.6.8, on darwin)
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-1.40.12 (TeX Live 2011/MacPorts 2011_5)
...
(...then the usual latex yada yada, including about 15 "errors"...)
...
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on test.log.
```

In case it is useful, here is the complete (and incorrect) LateX document produced by docutils :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
% generated by Docutils <http://docutils.sourceforge.net/>
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % LaTeX patches, \textsubscript
\usepackage{cmap} % fix search and cut-and-paste in Acrobat
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%%% Custom LaTeX preamble
% PDF Standard Fonts
\usepackage{mathptmx} % Times
\usepackage[scaled=.90]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}

%%% User specified packages and stylesheets

%%% Fallback definitions for Docutils-specific commands

% hyperlinks:
\ifthenelse{\isundefined{\hypersetup}}{
  \usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
  \urlstyle{same} % normal text font (alternatives: tt, rm, sf)
}{}
\hypersetup{
  pdftitle={This it the title},
}

%%% Title Data
\title{\phantomsection%
  This it the title%
  \label{this-it-the-title}}
\author{}
\date{}

%%% Body
\begin{document}
\maketitle

this is dummy text

\end{document}
```

Comment: Would you please attach also the generated `.tex` file?

Comment: I suggest using [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to process the `reStructured` text file.

Comment: @Sveinung thanks heaps for telling me about pandoc. I've just dropped docutils for pandoc, and I think I won't need to look back ever (I'm not even going to report the "bug" to docutils :-)

Comment: @Gyom: Note that pandoc does not support all the features of ReST.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the produced code

```
%%% Title Data
\title{\phantomsection%
  This it the title%
  \label{this-it-the-title}}
```

that works in `article` and other classes, but not in `memoir` because of untimely expansions.

A workaround would be persuading rst2latex to put `\protect` before `\phantomsection` and `\label`, but I really don't understand those commands inside `\title` should do.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation. My question is: why does docutils claim that it supports `memoir` when it generates such code (which clear purpose I don't understand either, btw) ?

Comment: Well the intention clearly is to make it possible to set a hyperlink to the title. As `\title` just saves its contents, it wouldn't be possible to put `\phantomsection` and `\label` outside its argument. I agree with egreg they need to be protected when put in such a place.

Comment: @Gyom The question you pose should be directed to the developers of DocUtils.

Comment: The implementation uses the same code to handle regular sectioning as well: chapters, sections and so on all get their `\phantomsection` and their `\label`. This does make some more sense, but yet it still upsets `memoir`. And now I wonder where I should report the bug: is that a `memoir` problem, or a `docutils` bug ?

Comment: @Gyom Definitely a problem with DocUtils. From what I can see in the primer documentation, section numbers are not automatically computed, so it would be *much* easier to set `secnumdepth` to -1000 and use `\chapter`, `\section` without `*`, `\phantomsection` and `\addcontentsline`.

Answer (score 0):

Gyom,

I suggest you the following [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/when-do-i-need-to-invoke-phantomsection), that explains that this instructions is needed when  hyperref is used with section headers not included in the TOC (sectional commands with an star) or when you include manually a title in the TOC, to reference correctly the heading and not a different paragraph.

Comment: thanks for that. However I now use ''pandoc'' (as per suggested in the comments above) and am much happier with it than Rst.  cheers.