# Customising ToC appearance of chapter titles in front and back matter

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref

This might be a duplicate, but I am interested in customising the ToC appearance of chapter titles for `\chapter` commands placed:

1. in the *front* and *back* matter, and
2. after the `\appendix` command in the *main* matter.

I only wish to change font series (to medium) and shape (to italic) as shown below. (Vertical spacing between front matter chapter titles probably needs to be reduced as well.)

[image]

At the moment I'm using the standard document class `book` and:

```
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % nottoc option for inclusion of LoT/LoF/Bib in ToC
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [solution of Gonzalo Medina](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84486/16967) uses package `titletoc` that does not work well with `hyperref`, because it extracts the heading number of the entry in the table of contents (and LOF, LOT) and sets it outside the link.

The following solution patches `\l@chapter`, `\l@section`, …, which are responsible for the formatting of the entry in the table of contents to add `\TocTitleFormat`. Depending on the switch `\ifTocMainMatter`, `\TocTitleFormat` does nothing or adds `\textit` for the title. If `\itshape` is used instead, also the page number would be in italic.

Similar to Medina's solution `\frontmatter` and friends are patched to add the setting of the switch `\ifTocMainMatter` into the `.toc` file.

Since `hyperref` is used, likely also bookmarks are generated. The same style can be applied to them via package `bookmark`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{numbered,open}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\PatchTocEntry}[1]{%
  \expandafter\@PatchTocEntry\csname l@#1\expandafter\endcsname
  \csname org@l@#1\endcsname{org@l@#1}%
}
\newcommand*{\@PatchTocEntry}[3]{%
  \@ifdefinable{#3}{%
    \let#2#1%
    \renewcommand*{#1}[1]{%
      #2{\TocTitleFormat{##1}}%
    }%
  }%
}
\@for\@tmp:=chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph\do{
  \PatchTocEntry{\@tmp}%
}
\newif\ifTocMainMatter
\let\ifTocMainMatter\if@mainmatter
\newcommand*{\SetTocMainMatter}[1]{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{%
    \expandafter\protect\csname TocMainMatter#1\endcsname
  }%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\bookmarksetup{%
      italic=\csname if#1\endcsname false\else true\fi
    }%
  }\x
}
\apptocmd{\frontmatter}{\SetTocMainMatter{false}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\mainmatter}{\SetTocMainMatter{true}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\appendix}{\SetTocMainMatter{false}}{}{}
\apptocmd{\backmatter}{\SetTocMainMatter{false}}{}{}
\newcommand*{\TocTitleFormat}[1]{%
  \ifTocMainMatter
    #1%
  \else
    \textit{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter  

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Results and Discussion}
\section{Section}
\section{Another Section}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\appendix

\chapter{My Appendix}
\section{Section in Appendix}
\cite{testa}

\backmatter

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testa} Author A, Title A, 2012
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Much to my ignorance, I am still only familiar with higher-level approaches to LaTeX, but your comment on `\itshape` was key for my understanding. So I changed `\textit{#1}` to `\normalfont\textit{#1}` when defining `\TocTitleFormat` and was able to achieve the desired result. Many thanks. (I've deleted the now irrelevant followup question.)

Answer (score 5):

One possibility using the [`titletoc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titletoc) package; the [`etoolbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package was used to patch `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, and `\appendix`, so as to automatically use the corresponding style:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand\frontformat{%
\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]
  {\itshape}{\contentslabel{0em}}
  {}{\normalfont\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}}
\newcommand\mainformat{%
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.4em]
  {\addvspace{10pt}\bfseries}{\contentslabel{1.15em}}
  {}{\normalfont\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\bfseries\contentspage}
}
\newcommand\backformat{%
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.5em]
  {\addvspace{10pt}\itshape}{\contentslabel{1.5em}}
  {\hspace*{-1.5em}}{\normalfont\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}}

\titlecontents{section}[3.8em]
  {}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}

\apptocmd{\frontmatter}{\frontformat}{}{}
\apptocmd{\mainmatter}{\mainformat}{}{}
\apptocmd{\appendix}{\backformat}{}{}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Preface}
\listoftables
\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\chapter{Results and Discussion}
\section{Section}
\section{Another Section}
\chapter{Conclusion}

\appendix

\chapter{My Appendix}
\cite{testa}

\backmatter

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem{testa} Author A, Title A, 2012
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. May I further suggest that you replace the lines `\chapter*{Preface}` and `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}` by **`\chapter{Preface}`** in your solution? The `\frontmatter` command already turns off chapter numbering. Plus `hyperref` deslikes `\addcontentsline`.

Comment: @nnunes yes, I was doing exactly that and other minor changes in the spacing; I've updated my answer.

Comment: My previous remark on `hyperref` and `\addcontentsline` was incorrect. Since `hyperref` 2009/11/25 v6.79h `\phantomsection` is no longer necessary when using the starred version of sectioning commands, see [.../44088/when-do-i-need-to-invoke-phantomsection](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/when-do-i-need-to-invoke-phantomsection).