# Formatting front matter title and page number in ToC to be single spaced and roman

Tags: table-of-contents, pdftex, memoir, pdfpages, front-matter

I want to achieve the following (ignore the artifacts, it's from a university reference for their thesis style),

[image]

I have the following MWE,

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside, parskip=full]{memoir}

\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3cm}{*} % Upper-Lower margins
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.8cm}{2.5cm}{*} % Left-Right margins
\checkandfixthelayout

%******************************
%      Table of con../fig../tab..
%*************************
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{LIST OF TABLES}
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{\centering\Large\bfseries #1}
\renewcommand{\printloftitle}[1]{\centering\Large\bfseries #1}
\renewcommand{\printlottitle}[1]{\centering\Large\bfseries #1}
\renewcommand{\chapternumberline}[1]{\MakeTextUppercase{\chaptername\ 
\numtoName{#1}: }}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}
\renewcommand{\cftchapterdotsep}{\cftdotsep}% Chapters should use dots in ToC
\usepackage{times} % Use Times font

%******************************
%      Spacing
%*************************
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.2cm} % Paragraph indent
\frenchspacing % Use single space after end of sentence

%******************************
%      Others
%*************************
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
%******************************
\frontmatter
%*************************
\includepdf[addtotoc={1,chapter,1,First Page,First Page}]{SamplePage.pdf}
\includepdf[addtotoc={1,chapter,1,Second Page,Second Page}]{SamplePage.pdf}
\includepdf[addtotoc={1,chapter,1,Third Page,Third Page}]{SamplePage.pdf}

\tableofcontents*
\listoftables
\listoffigures

%******************************
\mainmatter
%*************************
\DoubleSpacing
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[4-5]

%******************************
\backmatter
%*************************

\end{document}
```

Here is the code for `SamplePage.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\title{Sample Page}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[4-5]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

I've got the following so far,

[image: My Output]

I've already read [Customising ToC appearance of chapter titles in front and back matter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84436/customising-toc-appearance-of-chapter-titles-in-front-and-back-matter) but I don't think it applies here since I'm using `memoir`.

My questions:

1. How to make front matter titles and respective numbers be roman (un-bold)? <del>and have trailing dots in between them?</del>
2. How can I have single spacing between the front matter entries in the ToC?
3. How can I have "List of Figures" and "List of Tables" in the ToC but full caps in the `\title{}` and thus the page?
4. How can I make Chapter headings along with their titles in full caps?
5. <del>and also make chapter, and all sections, subsections, etc. have trailing dots to their respective page numbers?</del>