# How to create labels and references automatically in LaTeX?

Tags: macros, cross-referencing, etoolbox

I have defined two custom macros:

```
\translation{ORIGINAL}{TRANSLATION}
\printtranslations
```

The first macro prints out the translation and puts the original and the translation into a list. The list can be printed using the `\printtranslations` macro.

This is working great. However i also want to be able to jump inside the document between *translation* and *original*.

I tried using a refcounter but I couldn't figure out how to use it. At the moment I do not create labels automatically and always using the same reference to jump to the translation.

Here is my current code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{forloop}

% Macro creating a translation.
\def\mytranslations{}
\listadd{\mytranslations}{}
\newcommand{\translation}[2]{                                   %
    #2                                                          %
    \textsuperscript{                                           %
        \hspace{-0.2cm}                                         %
        (\hyperlink{chap:Translations}{Translation})            %
    }                                                           %
    \listgadd{\mytranslations}{#1\unexpanded{&}#2 \\}           %
}

% Macro showing all translations.
\newcommand{\showtranslations}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\printtranslations}{                                %
    {                                                           %
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}                        %
            \textbf{Original} & \textbf{Translation} \\         %
            \hline                                              %
            \forlistloop{\showtranslations}{\mytranslations} \\ %
        \end{tabularx}                                          %
    }                                                           %
}

\begin{document}
\translation{Bad}{Microsoft Word}
\clearpage
\translation{Good}{TeX} and \translation{Better}{LaTeX}
\clearpage 
\hypertarget{chap:Translations}
\printtranslations
\end{document}
```

Can someone pinpoint me into the right direction how to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Could you please complete your code so we have a working example?

Comment: I fear, you will get into some expansion problems

Comment: @cfr: Thx! I've added a minimal example.

Comment: @rednammoc: No, you have just copied part of my solution ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: The similarity is just a coincidence ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **not** the best solution but only a trial --> I splitted the original/translation pair into two lists which has to be traversed separately but allow for later transformation more easily.

Both lists are done in outer loop inside the table.

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{forloop}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{translation}

\listgadd{\myoriginals}{}%
%\gdef\mytranslations{}
\listgadd{\mytranslations}{}
\newcommand{\translation}[2]{%
  \refstepcounter{translation}%
  {\sethlcolor{Snow2}\hl{#2}}%\bookmark[dest=chap:Translations::\number\value{translation}]{#2}}%
  \textsuperscript{(\phantomsection\hyperlink{chap:Original::\number\value{translation}}{Translation})}%
  \listgadd{\myoriginals}{#1}%
  \listgadd{\mytranslations}{#2}%
}


\newcommand{\showorig}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{seconddummycounter}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{seconddummycounter}}{#1}{%
    \phantomsection\hypertarget{chap:Original::\number\value{seconddummycounter}}{#2}%
  }{%
  }%
}%


\newcommand{\showtrans}[2]{%
  \stepcounter{seconddummycounter}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{seconddummycounter}}{#1}{%
    #2%
  }{%
  }%
}%

\newcounter{dummycounter}%
\newcounter{seconddummycounter}%

\newcommand{\showall}{%
  \forloop{dummycounter}{1}{\number\value{dummycounter} < \numexpr\number\value{translation}+1}{%
    \setcounter{seconddummycounter}{0}  \forlistloop{\showorig{\number\value{dummycounter}}}{\myoriginals} & \setcounter{seconddummycounter}{0} \forlistloop{\showtrans{\number\value{dummycounter}}}{\mytranslations} \tabularnewline
    \hline
  }%
}%



% Macro showing all translations.

\newcommand{\printtranslations}{%
    {%                                                           %
      \tabulinesep=1.8mm                                      %
        \begin{longtabu}{XX}                                    %
        \textbf{Original} & \textbf{Translation} \tabularnewline         %
        \hline                                              %
        \showall
      \end{longtabu}                                          %
    }                                                           %
}


\begin{document}
\translation{Bad}{Microsoft Word}
\clearpage
\translation{Good}{TeX}
\translation{Very Good}{LaTeX}%
\clearpage



\clearpage
\printtranslations

\end{document}
```

[image]

The additional newline after the second column is a feature of `longtabu` I don't understand at the moment. Using a standard `tabular` it doesn't appear.

Comment: Thx for your answer and sorry for not providing any minimal example in the initial post.

Comment: Why do you initialize a second counter ("seconddummycounter").

Comment: @rednammoc: It's possible without doing it, most probably, but it took some time to understand what you want to achieve

Comment: @chistian-hupfer: to suppress the additional new-line the \noindent-command can be used. thx again for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This approach is hardly inspired by [the answer of Christian Hupfer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/220789/69968) whereby only one list is used which is a little bit closer to the code of [the original question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/220771/69968).

Following things were discovered answering this question:

- `\ref` requires a `\label`, whereby `\hyperlink` requires a `\hypertarget`.
- use `\phantomsection` in conjunction with `\hyperlink` and `\hypertarget` to get better results (as [described in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44091/69968)).
- do not let the `\hyperlink`-argument span over multiple lines of code since linebreaks might be recognized as part of the link.

  **Example:**

  ```
  \hyperlink{
     Chap:Translations
  }
  ```

  is not the same as

  ```
  \hyperlink{Chap:Translations}
  ```
- make use of the \noindent-command to suppress indentation.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{forloop}

\def\mytranslations{} %
\newcounter{mytranslationcounter} %
\listadd{\mytranslations}{} %
\newcommand{\translation}[2]{ %
    \refstepcounter{mytranslationcounter} %
    #2 %
    \textsuperscript{\hspace{-0.2cm}( %
        \phantomsection\hyperlink{chap:Translations::\number\value{mytranslationcounter}} %
        {Translation \number\value{mytranslationcounter}} %
    )} %
    \listgadd{\mytranslations}{#1 \unexpanded{&} #2} %
}

% Macro showing all translations
\newcounter{seconddummycounter} %
\newcommand{\showtrans}[2]{ %
  \stepcounter{seconddummycounter} %
  \ifnumequal{\value{seconddummycounter}}{#1}{ %
      \noindent\phantomsection\hypertarget{chap:Translations::\number\value{seconddummycounter}}{#2} %
  }{} %
} %
\newcounter{mytranslationindex} %
\newcommand{\showtranslations}{ %
    \forloop{mytranslationindex}{1} %
        {\number\value{mytranslationindex} < \numexpr\number\value{mytranslationcounter}+1}{ %
        \setcounter{seconddummycounter}{0} %
        \forlistloop{\showtrans{\number\value{mytranslationindex}}}{\mytranslations} \tabularnewline %
    } %
} %
\newcommand{\printtranslations}{                                %
    {                                                           %
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}                        %
            \textbf{Original} & \textbf{Translation} \\         %
            \hline                                              %
            \showtranslations \\                                %
        \end{tabularx}                                          %
    }                                                           %
}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\section{Text}
\translation{Bad}{Microsoft Word}
\clearpage
\translation{Good}{TeX} and \translation{Better}{LaTeX}
\clearpage 
\section{Translation}
\printtranslations
\end{document}
```