# Add abstract in TOC and correct link

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, abstract

I am using the `abstract` environment to write the abstract of a report (I am using the `report` class)

```
\begin{abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
lorem ...
\end{abstract}
```

I want to add the abstract to my table of contents. Adding the line `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}` seems to work fine (it adds the abstract in the toc) but when I click on it (I am using the package `hyperref`) in the TOC I am redirected to the first page of the report instead of the abstract page. Maybe I should precise that I am using the option `notitlepage` of the class `report` (I have a custom title page done with a `\begin{titlepage} ... \end{titlepage}` instruction).

Comment: Search for `\phantomsection` in the manual of the `hyperref` package (type `texdoc hyperref` at a terminal prompt, then search in the PDF document that your system should open in reply).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GuM suggested it in a comment, the solution is to use `\phantomsection`:

```
\begin{abstract}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
lorem ...
\end{abstract}
```

This other  [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088/when-do-i-need-to-invoke-phantomsection) was particularly useful.

Comment: `\phantomsection` should precede `\addcontentsline`.  Note that, even so, the target of the link is the first line of the abstract, not the title “Abstract”.