# \pageref give the wrong page link

Tags: cross-referencing

Consider the following simple example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
the first page
\clearpage
the second page  \label{key}
\clearpage
I want to return to page \pageref{key}, but return to page 1 when clicking the typeset number "2".
\end{document}
```

Why is the `\pageref` not working as expected?

Comment: Use `\phantomsection\label{key}` and try again.

Comment: @Werner nice! I deleted my comment because yours is easier and better way.

Comment: Related: [When do I need to invoke `\phantomsection`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44088/5764)

Comment: When I use \phantomsection\label close to \section, it jumps me to just below the sectional title, but I want the same line of the sectional title. How to deal with this?

Comment: @lyl if you want to refer to a real section you don't need a \phantomsection... Just put the label in the real section in this case