# How to change TOC counters without affecting the document?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, books

I am using book class with XeLaTeX. I want to change the toc counter 'I' (as shown here),
[image: 1]

with a bullet but redefining the Roman alphabets will also change the alphabets in the main document (as shown in here)

[image: 2]

which will then probably look like 'Part (bullet)' which makes no sense. Hence I want to separate the toc counter from the part definition.

MWE -

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\raggedright
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \part{The Part}
    \chapter{The Chapter}
    \section{The Section}
\end{document}
```

This is just an additional thought and not the main issue, but as I am also using hyperref and it automatically creates the outline for the pdf. As of now I am seeing the same entity which is in the part definition in the outline also.

[image]

This means if we replace the counter with a bullet it will be changed in the outline too, therefore I'll prefer a [unicode-based bullet](http://shapecatcher.com/unicode/info/8729). Is it possible?

Comment: If you look in the aux file, you will see `\numberline{I} The Part` which was created by \part using \addcontentsline.  You will have to modify \part to not do that.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490987/prevent-pagebreaks-before-and-after-part/490991?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#490991

Comment: But if I change \part, won't it also change the part name in the document? eg. I'm getting **I. Part** in the toc, which I don't want, but because of the same definition I'm also getting **Part I** in the document. I don't want to loose it. So is there any way to separate these two?

Comment: @JohnKormylo please check the screenshots attached.

Comment: The link was to show an example of replacing \part, not to implement your particular modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in book the formatting of the part entry in the toc is quite hard-coded. So you need to redefine an internal command (before loading hyperref). This will change both the toc and the bookmarks:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\@part{\thepart}{\textbullet}{}{\fail}
\makeatother
\raggedright
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \tableofcontents
    \mainmatter
    \part{The Part}
    \chapter{The Chapter}
    \section{The Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much man! Great job

Comment: I'm not a man, I'm a woman.

Comment: Lol. I'm sorry for that, but thanks a ton.

Comment: What if one wants to change the toc and not the outline? Is there any way to redefine toc separately and outline separately?

Comment: If you have a new question ask a new question don't ping only me for support.