# Error in Page numbering in table of contents

Tags: errors, numbering

I want to create a report for my project and I wrote a code but it is showing some error in table of contents.
The page numbering goes fine in the beginning but as chapter 1 starts its shows the numbering as 2 but in the document the page numbering is 1.
The document should be about 50 pages.
Here is the sample of the code I wrote:

```
  \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
  \usepackage{lipsum}
  \usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\bfseries\centering}{\huge Chapter \thechapter}{1em}{\Huge #1}
  \usepackage{pgf}
  \usepackage{pgfpages}

  \pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
  {
      \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
  }
  {
       \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
        {%
             logical pages=1,%
        }
       \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
        {
              border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%changes the width of border
              border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
              resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%change the size of border
              resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
              center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%make the border to 
              display in center
              }%
        }

 \pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage[a4paper,left=1.5in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{center}
 \thispagestyle{empty}
 \parskip=8pt%
 \vspace*{1\parskip}%
 \textbf{SYNCHRONOUS \& ASYNCHRONOUS DESIGN}

 \textbf{Project Title}

 A Project Report Submitted in Partial Fulfillment of the Requirements for the Degree of
 \parskip=20pt

 \textbf{Course}
 \parskip=4pt

 \textbf{Branch}

 \textit{By}

 \parskip=8pt%
 \textbf{Name of Student}

 \textbf{College ID}

 \begin{figure}[ht]
 \includegraphics[width=2.2098cm, height=2.2098cm]{image1}
 \centering
 \label{4}
 \end{figure}

 \textit{Under the supervision of}
 \parskip=24pt%


 \textbf{Guide Name}
 \parskip=4pt

 \textbf{Guide Designation}

 \textbf{Company Address}
 \begin{figure}[ht]
 \includegraphics[width=2.8cm, height=2.8cm]{image}
 \centering
 \label{7}
 \end{figure}

 \textbf{College Department}\\
 \textbf{College name}\\
 \textbf{College Address}\\
 \textbf{Jan-June (2020)}
 \end{center}

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CERTIFICATE}
 \chapter*{CERTIFICATE}
 \pagenumbering{roman}
  This is the certificate.

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}
 \chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}
  Acknowledgment 

 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
 \chapter*{ABSTRACT}
  Abstract goes here.....


 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
 \tableofcontents


 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
 \listoffigures


 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
 \listoftables


  \chapter{INTRODUCTION}
  \pagenumbering{arabic}
   Introduction

  \section{section}

  \subsection{part}

  \end{document}
```

I tried different solutions available online but none of them works for me.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `\phantomsection` might help with your numbering problem - see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44091/52743)

Comment: The problem is caused by the `\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}` --- don't use it and the ToC numbering is correct. I can't help with the `\pgfpagesuselayout` code but I don't like the result --- in your MWE the page numbers in the ToC extend into the black border.

Comment: I used \phantomsection command but it's still not working. Is there any other way? @fcbsd

Comment: @PrachiAgrawal The other way is described in the duplicate question (i.e., compile first one time without the boxed layout, then use the boxed layout with `\nofiles` and compile again). Arguably this is not a very convenient solution (and it can be called a bug in `pgfpages`, especially for `logical pages=1`), but it works.

Comment: @Marijn I tried that too but then there is a difference in numbering of the pages before introduction, i.e., numbering of certificate, abstract, acknowledgement, etc.

Comment: @PrachiAgrawal that is part of a different problem. For starred chapters `\addcontentsline` should come _after_ the chapter title. For the list of figures etc. it should come before, but you should clear the page first so `\addcontentsline` knows a new page is about to start. With that I get the following result: https://imgur.com/a/I25NT8r with the following code:

Comment: `\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}\nofiles` [...] `\chapter*{CERTIFICATE}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CERTIFICATE}
certificate
\chapter*{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ACKNOWLEDGMENT}
Ack.
\chapter*{ABSTRACT}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{ABSTRACT}
Abstract
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{CONTENTS}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF FIGURES}
\listoffigures
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF TABLES}
\listoftables
\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Intro`

Comment: Thank You @Marijn. I'll try this and let you know.

Comment: @PeterWilson I got the same issue earlier of the extended numbering into the border but now it's working fine.

Comment: @Marijn Thank you so much. My code is working fine now.