# ToC hyperlink to biblatex bibliography is not working for a specific class

Tags: biblatex, table-of-contents, hyperref

I am using the [fphw.cls](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/fphw-assignment) ([gitlab link](https://gitlab.com/fportales/fphw)) class for my assignment template.
But I have found that the hyperlink on my ToC to bibliography is not properly working. When I click on the bibliography section at my ToC (on PDF), it takes to the previous page of the bibliography.  The problem is appearing only in the bibliography. The other hyper-references are working okay.

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{fphw}    % Link to the fphw.cls file: https://gitlab.com/fportales/fphw/-/blob/master/fphw.cls
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[
     hidelinks,              % for removing the borders around clickable cross-references and hyperlinks 
     bookmarksopen,          % for PDF specific display option
     bookmarksnumbered,      % for PDF specific display option
]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}        % A new bookmark (outline) organization for hyperref
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{ToC to Bibliography Problem}
\addbibresource{ref_qm.bib} 
\begin{document}
\pdfbookmark[section]{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{section name}
\lipsum[1][5]\cite{book:griffiths} \\ \lipsum
\section{section name}
\lipsum[2][5]\cite{book:balakrishnan} \\ \lipsum 
\newpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

How can I solve the issue?
The fphw.cls file contains 126 lines of codes. That's why I haven't put it here. Kindly check the [link](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/fphw-assignment).

Comment: A relevant thread according to the answer of @Ulrike Fischer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44088/114006

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fphw` loads titlesec. titlesec is not fully compatible with hyperref. biblatex uses internally a `\section*` and a `\addcontentsline` command to setup the heading, but with titlesec it misses the anchor. The easiest is to add a `\phantomsection` manually:

```
\phantomsection\printbibliography
```

Comment: Thank you so much!