# Hyperref: remove links in internal references and footnotes

Tags: hyperref, reledmac

I have written a book and I invoked the hyperref package but the package produces some inconveniences:

1. I made use of `\label{}` to make internal references, hyperref misleads the page numbers: sometimes the reference is on p. 265 and the link (made by hyperref) sends to the page 250.
2. I don't need the footnotes linked.
3. As I use reledmac the familiar and critical notes appear linked by hyperref which is absolutely irrelevant and graphic noise.
4. Still I think hyperref is useful for linking the TOC and the URLS.

Is there a solution or is it better to dispense with hyperref?

```
\usepackage[series={A,B}]{reledmac}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[A]{paragraph}
\arrangementX[B]{paragraph}
\lineation{page}
\fnpos{familiar-critical}

\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false,colorlinks=false,linktocpage=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
A very simple idea, still it will be presented in two parts. The first will be deal in the context A (see \pageref{contextA}). The second will be analysed in the context B (see \pageref{contextB}).

This is the A context\label{contextA}. Here it goes the part 1 of simple idea\footnote{Though simple the idea requires some footnotes. But I would rather have them without hyperlinked anchors.}.

\newpage
This is the B context\label{contextB}. Here it goes the part 2 of simple idea.



\beginnumbering

\pstart
Que viaje à roda do seu \edtext{quarto}{\Afootnote{quarto (\textit{s. l.} A) \textit{AB} \textit{om. C}}} quem está à beira dos Alpes, de Inverno, em Turim, que é quase tão frio como Sampetersburgo — entende-se. Mas com este clima, com este ar que Deus nos deu, onde a laranjeira cresce na horta, e o mato é de murta, o próprio Xavier de Maistre,\footnoteA{XMM: pp. 1-3} que aqui escrevesse, ao menos ia até o quintal. Eu muitas vezes, nestas sufocadas noites de Estio, viajo até à minha janela para ver uma nesguita de Tejo que está no fim da rua, e me enganar com uns verdes de árvores que ali vegetam sua laboriosa infância nos entulhos do Cais do Sodré. E nunca escrevi estas minhas viagens nem as suas impressões: pois tinham muito que ver! Foi sempre ambiciosa a minha pena: pobre e soberba, quer assunto mais largo. Pois hei-de dar-lho. Vou nada menos que a Santarém: e protesto que de quanto vir e ouvir, de quanto eu pensar e sentir se há-de fazer crónica.
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

Comment: Add option `hidelinks` to hyperref (i.e. `\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}`. Perhaps you don't even need the other options.

Comment: Does this answer your issue no. 1? [When do I need to invoke `\phantomsection?`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62766/203961) (It is perfectly normal behavior for hyperref to send you to the beginning of a section, instead of the exact page or spot where a `\label` is invoked. This is the way labels were defined in LaTeX, long before hyperref came along. The solution is `\phantomsection`.)

Comment: As for issue no. 3 (no hyperlinks for the critical and familiar notes from `reledmac`), you could perform a bit of surgery on the command `\printlines` – if you are familiar with patching commands and willing to read the relevant lines of `reledmac.sty`.

Comment: you need a \phantomsection before the \label to get correct \pageref links. Regarding the footnote: that is reledmac's doing, it doesn't honor the hyperfootnotes setting, I would suggest to make a feature request.

Comment: Indeed, reledmac should follow hyperfootnote settting.