# Hyperref to Specific Text in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, hyperref

I am using Overleaf and I want to add a clickable link to a text.

I found methods to add a link that goes to a specific section / subsection, but I couldn't find any that goes to a specific text.

[image]

In the picture above, I want to make this "Theorem 1.3.1" clickable, so that I can teleport to that page immediately. This is what Theorem 1.3.1 looks like :

[image]

(Yes I know this page is weird and I'll fix it later because I'm still working on 1.1 and 1.2.)

The problem is that I wrote these theorem numbers as texts, like `\textbf{1.3.1}`.

How can I add such links? Is it even possible in the first place?

I think my question is understandable only with the fact that I used `\textbf{}` but I'll add some more codes for anyone who wants to know.

```
\subsection{Introduction to Linear Transformations}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{l@{}c@{}X}
\textbf{1.7.1} & $\quad$ & For every matrix $A$ the matrix transformation $T_{A} : 
\mathbb{R}^{n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{m}$ has the following properties for all vectors 
$\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ and for every scalar $k$ :
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{l@{}c@{}X}
$\qquad$ (a) $T_{A} (\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$ \\
$\qquad$ (b) $T_{A} (k \mathbf{u}) = k T_{A} (\mathbf{u})$ \null\hfill 
$\bm{\text{[Homogeneity property]}}$ \\
$\qquad$ (c) $T_{A} (\mathbf{u} + \mathbf{v}) = T_{A} (\mathbf{u}) + T_{A} (\mathbf{v})$ 
\null\hfill $\bm{\text{[Additivity property]}}$ \\
$\qquad$ (d) $T_{A} (\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}) = T_{A} (\mathbf{u}) - T_{A} (\mathbf{v})$ 
\\
\end{tabularx}

\begin{tabularx}{0.9\linewidth}{l@{}c@{}X}
\\
\textbf{Proof} & $\quad$ & All four parts are restatements from the transformation 
viewpoint of the following properties of matrix arithmetic given in \textbf{Theorem 
1.3.1} :
$$A \mathbf{0} = \mathbf{0}, \quad A(k \mathbf{u}) = k(A \mathbf{u}), \quad A(\mathbf{u} 
+ \mathbf{v}) = A \mathbf{u} + A \mathbf{v}, \quad A(\mathbf{u} - \mathbf{v}) = A 
\mathbf{u} - A \mathbf{v}$$
It follows from parts $\bm{(b)}$ and $\bm{(c)}$ of \textbf{Theorem 1.7.1} that a matrix 
transformation maps a linear combination of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ into the 
corresponding linear combination of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ in the sense that
\begin{equation}
T_{A} (k_{1} \mathbf{u_{1}} + k_{2} \mathbf{u_{2}} + \cdots + k_{r} \mathbf{u_{r}}) = 
k_{1} T_{A} (\mathbf{u_{1}}) + k_{2} T_{A} (\mathbf{u_{2}}) + \cdots + k_{r} T_{A} 
(\mathbf{u_{r}})
\end{equation}
$\blacksquare$ \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Please never ever just post sniplets, post full but minimal examples instead. Then others can copy and test your code as is. If your theorems are referable then you can use `\label{key}` plus `\hyperref[key]{text}`

Comment: @daleif I cannot post the whole thing since the whole thing is over 2000 lines. The whole thing is just that example being repeated over and over again, so I don't understand what I should have included.

Comment: @daleif Maybe you're talking about stuff like `\begin{document}` and `\usepackage{}`?

Comment: That is why it is called a **minimal** example. Yes, including relevant document class and packages.

Comment: BTW: why are you packing everything into tables? That seems to be a big waste of space and coding time.

Comment: [I've just been asked to write a minimal working example (MWE), what is that?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228)

Comment: You should not use tabulars for theorems and proofs, but theorem and proof environments, e.g. using [`amsthm`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsthm). Doing so, the numbering would be done automatically and you can use `\label`/`\ref` mechanism to reference and link them as usual. Manual numbering is almost always evil. If you insist in doing it manually, [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44088) should help. But I do not recommend to do so. Even using `enumerate` (maybe with [package `enumitem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) ) would be better than using manual numbering.

Comment: here is a little explanation about MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: @daleif That was the only solution I could find to align text after that "Proof" or "1.3.1". I know it takes a lot time but I already have sample codes I can paste and I've already made a hundred tables so I can't change it now :(

Comment: @cabohah Thanks, I've actually checked that package before but I wanted to change specific settings so I just numbered them manually. I may regret but I can't change it now...

Comment: you can add a target for a link with \hypertarget and a link with \hyperlink see the documentation of hyperref.